# Add a date field to SQL and convert the formatting to 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ'

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have an SQL running off a data view tabe and I need to add the ExtractDate to the target Data extensio.Date field doesn't exist in this Dataview tablem so apart from adding it, I need to convert the formatting to 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ' format when adding to an existing SQL.
I tried a few ways of doing this but I'm always getting the same format such as '12 April 2023 3:07PM'.
Could you please advise the best statement to use in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FORMAT` function to get the format you want.

For example:

```
SELECT
GETDATE() AS now,
FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ') AS formarted_date
FROM
[DE name]
```

Result:

```
Now: Apr 20 2023 1:00AM 
formarted_date: 2023-04-20T01:00:02.800Z
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_format.asp